# How to keep Hibernate logs out of SystemOut.log?

Tags: hibernate, log4j

I've configured the following loggers:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG,applicationLog,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG,applicationLog,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INFO,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=INFO,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=INFO,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=DEBUG,applicationLog,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=INFO,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=INFO,hibernateLog
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=INFO,hibernateLog
```

Both applicationLog and hibernateLog are rolling file appenders. I get messages into these log files so that seems to work.

However, I still see Hibernate messages appended to SystemOut.log file.

```
00000069 SystemOut     O Hibernate: select myTableName...
```

I'm on WAS 8 with Hibernate 4.2.7.